# OpenMPI runtime error : Hello World

Tags: openmpi

I'm able to successfully compile my code when I execute the make command. However, when I run the code as:

```
mpirun -np 4 test
```

The error generated is:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[63067,1],2]
  Exit code:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have no multiple mpi installations so I don't expect there to be a problem.

I've been having trouble with my Hello World OpenMPI program. My main file is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int size, rank;

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    cout << "The number of spawned processes are " << size << "And this is the process " << rank;

    MPI_Finalize();


    return 0;

}
```

My makefile is:

```
# Compiler 
CXX = mpic++

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS = -Wall -lm

# Header and Library Paths
INCLUDE = -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/lib -I..
LIBRARY_INCLUDE = -L/usr/local/lib
LIBRARIES = -l mpi

# the build target executable
TARGET = test

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) main.cpp $(INCLUDE) $(LIBRARY_INCLUDE) $(LIBRARIES)


clean:
    rm $(TARGET)
```

The output of: `mpic++ --version` is:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

And that for `mpirun --version` is:

```
mpirun (Open MPI) 2.1.1

Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/
```

What could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now resolved. It turns out that I have to execute with

```
mpirun -np 4 ./test
```

Ref: users-request@lists.open-mpi.org